# JavaScript, UWP: Backgroundtask tracking keypress events

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, winapi, uwp

Hey I'm new to the Universal Windows Platform and the belonging API's.
I'm trying to build an UWP Application in JS.

**Question 1:**
How would I initialize and listen for a background task (in js)?

**Question 2:**
And how, if possible, would the background task listen for any keypress of a specific combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: How would I initialize and listen for a background task (in js)?

1. Firstly, you need to create a Runtime Component and Create a BackgroundTask Class, which implements [Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.IBackgroundTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.ibackgroundtask). For details please refer to `Create a BackgroundTask Class` section of [Official Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task).
2. Secondly, register the backgroundTask in `package.appxmanifest`:
   [image]
3. Thirdly,register backgroundTask in js codes:

   ```
   (function () {
   "use strict"
   //Initialization
   var Background = Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
   //Register
   var taskBuilder = new Background.BackgroundTaskBuilder();
   taskBuilder.name = "MyBackgroundTask";
   //init trigger
   var appTrigger = new Background.ApplicationTrigger();
   taskBuilder.taskEntryPoint = "MyRuntimeComponent.MyBackgroundTask";
   taskBuilder.setTrigger(appTrigger);
   //Check if background task already registered
   var taskRegistered = false;
   var iter = Background.BackgroundTaskRegistration.allTasks.first();
   var hascur=iter.hasCurrent;
   while (hascur)
   {
       var current = iter.current.value;
       if (current.name == "MyBackgroundTask")
       {
           taskRegistered = true;
           break;
       }
       iter.moveNext();
   }

   if (!taskRegistered)
   {
       taskBuilder.register();
   }

   //click event
   document.getElementById("btnClick").onclick = function (evt)
   {
       appTrigger.requestAsync().then(function (result) {
           var abc = result;
       }, function (err) {
           console.log(err);
       })
   }
   })();
   ```

> Question 2: And how, if possible, would the background task listen for any keypress of a specific combination.

You can set an [ApplicationTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.applicationtrigger) for your backgroundtask and in click event function call the `ApplicationTrigger.requestAsync`:

```
document.getElementById("btnClick").onclick = function (evt)
{
    appTrigger.requestAsync().then(function (result) {
        var abc = result;
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your extremely helpful post! I get the following error when I execute the js initialization: `0x80040154 - JavaScript runtime error: Class not registered` So I guess some called Class has not been initialized. I am also unsure about linking the Runtime Component to the UWP Project. So I linked the Component under References (don't know if that is wrong) - [here](https://github.com/jonhue/my_clipboard)  you can find the source, if needed

Comment: I was able to fix that problem. What should I need to take instead of `appTrigger` in the `onclick` event?

Comment: `appTrigger` is the `ApplicationTrigger`  that I initialized by `var appTrigger = new Background.ApplicationTrigger();` in my codes

Comment: Ah ok. And how (Question 2) would I listen (in C#) for keypress events?

Comment: If you mean you want  backgroundTask to listen for the keypress events and register the keypress handler in `RuntimeComponent`. There is no way to do that. BackgroundTask runs in a separate process while your keypress events runs in the UI Thread.